# Troubleshooting SharePoint Online word document instability

Tags: sharepoint-online, document, word, collaboration

I have a group of users all editing the same word document concurrently (maybe 5 or so at a time) and they are intermittantly experiencing problems inputting data. I am getting reports of the cursor jumping around the screen or overwriting text just inputted and not saving properly and this will apparenlty go on for hours.

I've so far not seen it for myself but have requested they do a Teams screen share with me next time it happens.

Is there anything I could be looking for that might be the source or is this just an issue with SharePoint being unable to handle so many people working on the same document? The document itself is quite large (50+ pages) and is itself a smaller part of an even larger document they were working on previously.

The only possible solution I can think of is to just cut it down again into smaller chunks.

Does anyone have any other soultions? Could this be a result of Covid-19 pushing more people into working online which in turn might be causing strain on Microsoft's servers?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to start with, but the answer is going to be open a support case via admin.microsoft.com.

- If you have an SSL decryption service/proxy, make sure to put the domains/IPs/IP ranges on a bypass list: [Office 365 URLs and IP address ranges](https://docs.microsoft.com/office365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges).
- Verify Major Versions are enabled on the Document Library the document resides in. By default SharePoint Online sets libraries to 500 major versions.
- Verify that Auto-Save is enabled in Word
- Verify that you have a current version of Word/Office (and only Office 365 desktop is supported for real-time co-authoring)

5 people isn't an issue nor should the document length/size be an issue.

The best thing to do is open a case with Microsoft. They will provide you logging tools, but you'll need to reproduce the issue while those tools are running.

Comment: Thanks for this will have to check point 1. Point 2 is the case, the document library settings haven't been changed from default. for Point 3, is this done on a per-document basis? and for point 4 all users have the latest version of word on their devices (we have Microsoft Managed Devices and all are recently updated)

I will take your advice and go to Microsoft with this too.